# Swapping variable places inside if throws an error

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
for i in range(len(data_list) - 1):
    if(data_list[i] == 0):
        continue;
    timeline[int(int(data_list[i][1:]) / FIFTEEN_MINUTE_MS)] += 1;
    k = i + 1;
    while k < len(data_list) - 1:
        if data_list[i][0] == data_list[k][0]:
            print(data_list[i]);
            print(data_list[k]);
            tyre1 = int(data_list[i][1:]);
            tyre2 = int(data_list[k][1:]);

            #Error here
            if((tyre2 - tyre1) < TWENTY_MPH and (tyre2 - tyre1) > SIXTY_MPH):
                print(data_list);
                if data_list[i][:1] == 'A':
                    if data_list[i + 1][:1] == 'A':
                        north += 1;
                    else:
                        south += 1;
                data_list[i] = 0;
                data_list[k] = 0;
                break;
            else:
                k += 1;
        else:
            k += 1;
```

This code runs fine and I get an output. But when I swap tyre1 and tyre2 inside the if statement like this

```
if(tyre2 - tyre1 < TWENTY_MPH and tyre2 - tyre1 > SIXTY_MPH):
```

I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
    data_analyse(data_list)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\data.py", line 19, in data_analyse
    if data_list[i][:1] == data_list[k][:1]:
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

What am I not seeing?

Edit:

Information about data_list

```
data_list = ['A268981', 'A269123', 'A604957', 'B604960', 'A605128', 'B605132', 'A1089807', 'B1089810', 'A1089948', 'B1089951']
```

Why am I getting downvoted without anyone telling the reason? Doesn't make it easy for a beginner to ask questions here.

Edit 2: added print statements to check for integers

```
i: 0
k: 1
A268981
A269123
['A268981', 'A269123', 'A604957', 'B604960', 'A605128', 'B605132', 'A1089807', 'B1089810', 'A1089948', 'B1089951']
i: 2
k: 4
A604957
A605128
[0, 0, 'A604957', 'B604960', 'A605128', 'B605132', 'A1089807', 'B1089810', 'A1089948', 'B1089951']
```

Value for the constants

```
TWENTY_MPH = 280
SIXTY_MPH = 100
```

Comment: Well the error is clear `data_list[i]` is already an integer, so you cannot add `[:1]` on it.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem data_list = ['A268981', 'A269123', 'A604957', 'B604960', 'A605128', 'B605132', 'A1089807', 'B1089810', 'A1089948', 'B1089951'];

Comment: On a side note, that comparison is pretty ambiguous tho. Not sure if what it does is what you intend

Comment: @MosesKoledoye seems to work as intended with the variables switched. I'm trying to check if both the strings start with 'A'

Comment: Yep, I think you're fine, the `-` operation is evaluated first

Answer (score 0):

I think you algorithm should be rethought.

Basically what you're doing is

```
for i in [0..N]:
    for k in [i..N]:
        my_string_1 = data[i][0]
        my_string_2 = data[k][0]
        if my_string_1 == my_string_2:
            data[i] = 0
            data[k] = 0
```

The issue here is that at some point, the condition is verified and you assign `0` to `data[k]`, but then in another i-loop iteration, for the same `k` value you read this value back and treat it as if it was some of those `'A268981'` strings, which fails.

Example:

```
i = 3
k = 7
data[k] = 0
```

then later

```
i = 5
k = 7
data[k][0]  <-- error
```

I didn't run your code but I suppose this may or may not happen depending on the other condition `if(tyre1 - tyre2 < TWENTY_MPH and tyre1 - tyre2 > SIXTY_MPH):`, which is why you see it or not depending on that condition.

Also, I don't know what those constants are, but I don't see how the same value could be both < 20 and > 60. You should post those values as well.

Note: when dealing with strings, `data_list[i][0]` is equivalent to and more readable in my opinion than `data_list[i][:1]`.

Comment: That's what I thought too. So I added a print statement before the condition. Added it to the original question.

Comment: You didn't edit the code to show where those `print` statements are, but it looks like what I said, doesn't it?

Comment: I added the prints. And no, they are not ints during the assignment.

Comment: While you're at it, you might as well print i and k, data_list[i] and data_list[k] just before the line that crashes.

Comment: I just added that mate